# Making an executable by running an executable

Tags: c++, c, elf, brainfuck

<s>I wanted to write a brainfuck compiler, but when I went to write one I was stuck at this problem</s>

<s>I want to create an ELF executable (using C/C++) that reads a brainfuck code from a file and generates an executable. Just like GCC/clang</s>

<s>I can read and parse the code, but I don't know how to write an executable that can run on the same system (say x86)?</s>

<s>I want this behavior:</s>

    <s>my_bf_compiler ./source.bf -o bin.out
    ./bin.out</s>

EDIT: **I do not want to know how to write a compiler. Read this, compiler part was just for context as to where I will use it**

I want to create a binary executable (say maker.out) which when ran creates a executable file (say foo.out). For simplicity let's keep `foo.out` very simple, when executed it returns 7; So, this is what is expected:

```
./maker.out # Creates the foo.out executable
./foo.out && echo $ # Runs the executable and prints return value, in this case 7;
```

So how do I write maker.cpp?

Comment: If you want to write an elf binary that's always the same, just embed it in your program and write that embedded resource to file.

Comment: So you want to write an ELF executable. What research have you done into the ELF format? Have you looked at any documentation, or ELF libraries, or at the ELF sections in existing executables, or ... done any research?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your initial message was about creating a an executable from a brainfuck code, so this is what this answer focuses on. Your current question is way too broad.

As you have linked in one of your previous posts there is already an implementation that does this here: https://github.com/skeeto/bf-x86/blob/master/bf-x86.c

It basically does 3 steps:

1) Parse the BF code into a intermediate representation (which is here https://github.com/skeeto/bf-x86/blob/master/bf-x86.c#L55)

2) Compile this intermediate representation into machine code (which can be found here https://github.com/skeeto/bf-x86/blob/master/bf-x86.c#L496)

3) Compose the ELF binary according to the specification. The example program does this here. https://github.com/skeeto/bf-x86/blob/master/bf-x86.c#L622 .

Steps 1 and 2 are up to you to find a good implementation, for step 3 the simplest way is to write the ELF header and program header in such a way, that it only has the programs machine code as content and point the entrypoint of the program to the machine code generated in step 2.

The full specification for the ELF format can be found here: https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/elf/elf.pdf

Answer (score 1):

@Yanick's answer contains enough information about the ELF format and how to create an elf executable.

However, it seems to me that your question is about how to open/create an executable file. There is a function called `chmod/fchmod` which might help you.

The following text is taken from the man-page for `chmod` (run `man 2 chmod` to see this page):

```
   #include <sys/stat.h>
   int chmod(const char *pathname, mode_t mode);
   int fchmod(int fd, mode_t mode);

   The new file mode is specified in mode, which is a bit mask created by ORing together zero or  more  of  the
   following:

   S_ISUID  (04000)  set-user-ID (set process effective user ID on execve(2))

   S_ISGID  (02000)  set-group-ID (set process effective group ID on execve(2); mandatory locking, as described
                     in fcntl(2); take a new file's group from parent directory, as described in  chown(2)  and
                     mkdir(2))

   S_ISVTX  (01000)  sticky bit (restricted deletion flag, as described in unlink(2))

   S_IRUSR  (00400)  read by owner

   S_IWUSR  (00200)  write by owner

   S_IXUSR  (00100)  execute/search  by  owner ("search" applies for directories, and means that entries within
                     the directory can be accessed)

   S_IRGRP  (00040)  read by group

   S_IWGRP  (00020)  write by group

   S_IXGRP  (00010)  execute/search by group

   S_IROTH  (00004)  read by others

   S_IWOTH  (00002)  write by others

   S_IXOTH  (00001)  execute/search by others
```

In your case, running `chmod("foo.out", S_IRUSR | S_IXUSR)` should give you(the owner) the permission to read and execute foo.out. Assuming that you have written `foo.out` to be a proper elf file, this will make it executable.